# Firefox not using cache?

Tags: firefox, performance, browser-cache

Some times I have issues with the wireless connection where I live.  That issue is irrelevant to this (there are two IT departments managing this thing; there's nothing I can do about it).  Most of the time it's nice and fast, but sometimes slows to a crawl (single digit KB/s sorts of crawl).

Anyway, I think Firefox (11.0 Ubuntu) might not be using its cache correctly.  When (for testing purposes) I set it to "Work Offline", pages load on the order of a second.  Normally, the same page (benchmarked on http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries ) loads in around three seconds when the connection is working properly, and ten or more when it's not.  I can confirm it's reloading things, since I see a spike on my bandwidth-use graph while when I open the page.  I think image caching is still working properly, since it doesn't seem to be very much bandwidth used though.

Shouldn't Firefox just be using the cached copy of the page (checked; exists in the disk cache) instead of downloading a new copy, when I open the page in a new tab?

I know that some content is set to expire, so it should download a new copy.  I don't believe that the example page has one of those.  Under "Work Offline", pages like gmail did not load, so I assume that *that* is the proper behavior of pages that expire.

How can I either make firefox use cache unless the page has expired, or, better yet, display the cached page while it tries to load a new copy?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to install the [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/) and disable cache on it.

Comment: But @zebediah49 wants to do the opposite. ;-)

Comment: That is right. My mistake :)